# Android: Error Atrribute has already been defined

Tags: android

I am a new user, and I have a problem errors here. is there that can help me how to fix it's?
my messages gradle build

```html
   
Error:(2) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "icon" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "logo" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "divider" has already been defined

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\MRX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

my build gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.matrix_center.cloningapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you using  `ActionBarSherlock` ??

Comment: no use ActionBarSherlcok sir

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve this by using the same version of the support library in all of your project's libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your attrs.xml might have duplicate entries try removing them or renaming them. Worked for me.